# Accessing parent instance in child creation callbacks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, has-many

If I create an object using the association:

```
post.comments.create 'blah'
```

Is there any way to access the parent instance during the object's creation?

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base

  def before_save
    # do something with @post
  end

end
```

I find the parent instance is nil before saving and not the same instance after saving.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you simply access the 'post_id' attribute in before_save block? Or if you define 'belongs_to :post' association in comment.rb model, you should be able to access 'self.post' too in before_save method. Please give it a try

Comment: I can access post_id or use self.post, but I can't get a handle on the original "post" *instance* as I want to set an attribute on it.

Comment: I'm not sure with your code, but when you create comment using post instance like you showed, that should have 'post' object initiated with particular record. And as it belongs to 'Post' class, you can access any methods on that instance. Can you share something, so that I can understand your issue better?

Comment: @Sean yes, doable I think. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using `post.comments.new` will ensure the association ID is assigned without saving the new comment. So `before_save` should be able to access the parent (`comment.post`) when you do save it. ie save it in 2 stages:

```
comment = posts.comments.new
...
comment.save!
```

You could of course wrap it in a single creation function on the parent (Post) if you wanted a one-liner creation.

(It's also possible more recent Rails would actually work for the scenario posed in the question, ie just a simple `post.comments.create` but I haven't tested.)